# Strange use of class's variable (micro optimization ?)

Tags: php

I'm fairly new in PHP, and I encounter what I see as a strange use of class variable (I use PHP 5.6 and I think to use 7.0, if that help).

```
Class Foo {

    private $bar = 'some string not returned nor modified and used in one place';

    public function Test($foobar)
    {
        if ($foobar === $this->bar) {
            // Some code
        } else {
            // Some code
        }
    }
}
```

When I see above code, I asked my co-worker why $bar is declared as a class variable, and why not declare $bar only in method 'Test'.
He answered by explaining me that declaring $bar in Test would result on a performance loss since each time method 'Test' will be call, it will result in re-create memory space for $bar variable.

I'm little puzzled, is this true ? I understand the logic : if you declare your variable as a class variable, memory will be "allocated" once and not at each call, but I'm surprised that there is no automatic optimization to do this behind the curtain by php.

Is this an old optimization ? It's a good thing to declare as much as possible variable as class variable ?

Sorry for such a question, but I searched a little and I found nothing (mostly because I don't know which keyword I must type to get information on this particular subject).

Comment: `$bar` is an instance variable not a (static) class variable; and should be referenced as `$this->bar`, not as `$self::bar`.... and if `$bar` was static, then it would be `self::$bar`, not `$self::bar`

Comment: I corrected, thanks.

Comment: If the string is as simple as in your example, I'd say this is a micro-optimization with negligible performance improvement, which actually makes the code harder to read.

Comment: In my case, it's effectively just a string, but my question is available for other variable type (object, array ...). If this is a real optimization, it worth to put as much local variable's method on class variable.

Comment: Is `$this->bar` (potentially) referenced more than once in the class? Then that alone justifies it.

Comment: If `$bar` was purely a "function" variable, it wouldn't retain its value between calls to Test() unless it was defined as a static, so a line like `if ($foobar === $bar) {` would be pretty meaningless

Comment: And while there may be a slight saving with memory allocation/deallocation; there is also a slight performance overhead to accessing an instance property compared with a local variable.... it is a micro-optimisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty benchmark I have done with PHP 7.0 on my computer. I created three classes:

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar = 'some string not returned nor modified and used in one place';
    public function test($foobar)
    {
        if ($foobar === $this->bar) {}
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public function test($foobar)
    {
        $bar =  'some string not returned nor modified and used in one place';
        if ($foobar === $bar) {}
    }
}

class Baz
{
    public function test($foobar)
    {
        if ($foobar === 'some string not returned nor modified and used in one place') {}
    }
}
```

Then run something like:

```
$a = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<10000000; $i++) {
    (new Foo)->test('pop');
}
echo microtime(true) - $a . "\n";
```

I runned it on each classes 10 times, and what I got is **Bar and Baz seems to be faster every time**.

So it's the exact opposite as what your coworker said.

Here is a sample result:

```
1.3472490310669 # foo
1.1803860664368 # bar
1.0683979988098 # baz
```

That said, two words:

- My benchmark is dirty and does not prove anything.
- I usually don't care about this kind of optimization (but I think you are already aware of micro-optimization debate)

Comment: Well other question could be memory usage, but still - if your bench result is reliable, then it definitely disprove the "co-workers" performance loss statement.

Comment: Post the results of your benchmark. The numbers clearly show that it's a micro-optimization.

Comment: You should add a static for fun. I guess that is how you may get any optimalizations

Comment: I added a sample result. Still it's not really reliable, but it what about their benchmarks? Are they more reliable?

Comment: @axiac I added a sample result. All results are almost the same.

Comment: @rap-2-h result numbers aren't really that surprising to me. Baz being fastest kind of makes sense. You should try to bench calling class functions without creating new object as well... Then Foo could probably render faster than Bar IMO

Comment: I did a benchmark with a static variant. It is faster than Foo and Bar, but slower than Baz.

Comment: @nl-x Thanks! Feel free to edit my post if you want!

Comment: As I fear, there isn't a true and definitve answer when it come to this kind of stuff. We did the same benchmark and the result it's rougthly the same (except it take us twice your time). We choose to do the "Bar" exemple in our program. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom's How much more proof do you want? It's quite definitive. Your colleague is wrong. (And btw, my computer takes 30x as much time :( )